# If I move from shared hosting to VPS hosting, but my email box will stay local would I still need to massively configure email DNS records?

Tags: email-accounts

I currently host a MediaWiki website on a shared CentOS, Apache, MySQL, PHP environment.

I was thinking that sometime in the future I might migrate the website database, filetree and email hosting to a *generally non managed VPS hosting* (such as Linode, DigitalOcean), because such hostings tend to cost less and be faster, but, for sure I wouldn't want to start doing crazy email DNS record configurations also.

Assuming that I change my current shared website hosting to a VPS hosting, but my email box will stay local,
(i.e. I **wouldn't** send contact-form emails to my Gmail email account, rather, to a local Postfix-Dovecote-Roundcube[?] email account),
In such case, would I still need to massively configure email DNS records, as I would have to do **if I did want** to transfer contact-form emails to my Gmail email account?

### Update

In my shared hosting environment I didn't configure any DNS records so I don't move any DNS record configurations if I migrate my website to a VPS; furthermore, I would be glad not to configure any DNS record besides an `A` record (and to top that with an HTTPS global redirect cherry in `.htaccess`) because I just hate configuring DNS records.

Comment: As far as delivering email to your Gmail account, you can configure mail delivery from your VPS to send email through Gmail with your user and password.  I do so with the Exim4 mail-transfer-agent: [How do I configure exim4 to send mail through a password protected ssl smtp mail server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167043/how-do-i-configure-exim4-to-send-mail-through-a-password-protected-ssl-smtp-mail)

Answer (score 3):

This depends on how DNS is configured. If its been done to best practices Your email records would remain largely the same, save that you might need to add the IP address of your vps to your SPF record and add DKIM records if applicable.

This assumes that you are relying on a subdomain/subdomains (eg mail.example.com rather then example.com).

If you are worried about DKIM,/SPF changes the alternative is to relay outbound email through your current mail server - in which event the wikimedia server behaves like any other MUA.. Ive not used Wikimedia, but this looks to be supported - https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSMTP

Comment: Hello David, I think I might have done shitty job explaining my problem or you misunderstood me (I say it very it carefully) ; I don't want to configure DNS records besides an A record (and to top that with an HTTPS global redirect cherry)

Comment: Unfortunately your comment does not tell me anything more about your setup, so my answer is as correct as it was and can be even taking into account your comment.  The best anyone can say about only changing your A record is "maybe it will work, maybe it won't.  It depends on how you send email and what your SMTP and IMAP server names are set to."

Answer (score 3):

Further to the answer from @davidgo.  The best way to avoid any down time is to set up DNS in advance.

Make your `MX record` point to `mail.example.com` and then an `A Record` for `mail.example.com` pointing to the IP address of your mail server - which it sounds like will remain unchanged.

Doing this separates the MX from the primary domain so that when you update the A Record of the primary domain, it won't affect email at all.